# Primary Key setting for Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a database that has few tables and views.
Views are combination of 2 to 3 tables.
I have created entity model from that db, and all worked well.
The only problem I am facing is that entity model is making all the fields in view as primary key.

Is there a way to tell entity model which field to use as primary key? or I should simply ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the designer you can set the properties that need to be used as 'entity key' property. Key meaning the primary key.

[image]

Comment: I have designed database first and imported it into entity model, I don't see any option like this now

Comment: I just imported a view and can still change it... it's in the properties window when you select a property of the entity on the designer.

Comment: Thanks. I was clicking entity instead of entity field.